# If the PETRA accelerator only goes up to 45GeV, how can we know that Lambda of quark/lepton constituents would be greater than 750GeV?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

If the PETRA accelerator only goes up to 45GeV, how can we know that Lambda of quark/lepton constituents would be greater than 750GeV, according to the 1983 article [New Tests for Quark and Lepton Substructure](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.50.811)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looking for compositeness](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-searches-quark-lep-compositeness.pdf) functions are fitted to data according to predictions of specific models.

The function has a Λ giving the scale in energy where the composite particles will have to appear in experiments.

This can be left variable in a fit of the data to the model predictions. Thus even for much lower energies ,  if the data are very accurate, a limit can be given for the Λ fitted in the formula dependent on the errors of the measurements.